# DirectShow Auto Resize

Tags: c#, video, directshow, directshow.net

I was using my directshow app as an in-process library.
However now I need to run it as a separate background process.
So rendering surface is on another process.
I'm passing handle (hwnd) of the render surface (picturebox) to the background process.

Previously I had this for resizing; ( Since it was in same process and I have access to the Control directly)

```
...      
m_VideoControl.Resize += new EventHandler(VideoControl_Resize); 
...

private void VideoControl_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lock (m_csAsyncLock)
            {
                ResizeVideoWindow();
            }
        }

protected virtual void ResizeVideoWindow()
        {
            if (m_VideoWindow != null && m_VideoControl != null)
            {
                m_VideoWindow.SetWindowPosition(0, 0, m_VideoControl.Width, m_VideoControl.Height);
            }
        }
```

However now I don't have access to the direct Control so I can not subscribe to the VideoControl_Resize event.
I only have the handle of the control.

How can I make my video to resize if external control is resized?

If possible I don't want to use a new filter and solve it like before SetWindowPosition function?

Answer (score 1):

If your instance of video renderer filter is running in context of another process, your Resize handler needs to pass control to that process by posting a message or otherwise using interprocess communication, and receiving the event in the other process you are to call `IVideoWindow.SetWindowPosition` there, in the process where video renderer runs.

In order to make it more convenient, I would offload not just a graph with a video renderer to a helper process, but also a hosting window or control. This way it is sufficient for a parent UI handler to resize the children the usual normal way, cross process communication would take place between the windows, and helper process window will receive again normal UI messages and events letting you handle them the direct way and manage your DirectShow video renderers.

Comment: Hi Roman, I managed to get current size with;
RECT rec = new RECT();
                GetWindowRect(m_VideoControlHandle, ref rec);
                m_VideoWindow.SetWindowPosition(0, 0, rec.Right - rec.Left, rec.Bottom - rec.Top ); How can I make this called at each sample render without a filter?

Comment: Having video renderer and hosting UI in different processes, you have to take care of interprocess communication. That is, it is not about filters exactly, it is about how you structure your application and UI handlers.

Comment: I have another(actually a couple of more) sample apps which is written by someone else and closed-source. But we know that it doesn't use any kind of IPC but it can do video window resizing automatically just with hwnd. Is it bad idea to set a timer and constantly query GetWindowRect and call SetWindowPosition?

Comment: Polling position with timer might be a more or less acceptable workaround if you cannot handle the UI layout updates more accurately, using events and handlers.

Comment: What if I write a transform filter and at each sample callback set the video window size by getting with GetWindowRect?

Comment: You can do it but it is rather a workaround like with a timer (of the two I would prefer timer).